# Auto-migrations to dynamic contexts for multi tenant databases

Tags: c#, entity-framework, multi-tenant, entity-framework-migrations

Until now, I have been using automatic migrations to update my database from my model. I have now updated the `dbContext()` constructor from using a `web.config` database connection string, to dynamically setting the connection string context based on the user/company. This is built by looking up the details from another database.

This all works well until I make changes to my model. I can no longer run `update-database` from the Package Manager Console to update my database as there is no reference to a database instance in the code.

How do I now make the changes to my databases?

```
public MyContext() : base(ConnectionString())
{
}

private static string ConnectionString()
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    sqlBuilder.DataSource = CurrentCompany.DataSource;
    sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = CurrentCompany.InitialCatalog; 
    sqlBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;
    sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
    return sqlBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add following line before the first database call:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MyContextConfiguration>());
```

It will execute all pending (or automatic) migrations on MyContext creation.

Comment: Many thanks - I added this code to `Application_Start()` in global.asax.cs

Comment: Is there a way to force a migration to run when the migration results in data loss? In the same way that I would use `update-database -force` from the Package Manager Console?

Comment: Add `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;` line to your configuration class constructor.